# Placeholder for broken image fails in IE11, using holder.js and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11, holder.js

I try to setup a placeholder for broken image, using holder.js in an AngularJS framework.

Everything works perfectly on all browsers, except with IE11 (what a surprise!), which gives me a strange "invalid property value" error... I did not even test with older versions of IE.

So, it works when :

- I use `"holder.js/100%x100%"` directly in the `src` attribute (with no additionnal directive)
- I use `"holder.js/100x100"` as a placeholder for broken image

But it fails when :

- I use `"holder.js/100%x100%"` directly in a `data-ng-src` instead of `src` ( => invalid argument)
- I use `"holder.js/100%x100%"` as a placeholder for broken image ( => invalid property value)

After few other tests (with jQuery or pure javascript), I figured out the error does not come from holder.js. I rather think there is an issue with IE11 when using `%` character in src/ngSrc attributes programmatically ... but I don't know why if I'm right.

---

Here is the fiddle with the four use cases :

**http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/184fseew/**

If anybody has an idea about the reason or the way to get it working.

Thx for your help...

---

**EDIT :**

Thx to @imsky, here a working fiddle, using `data-src` instead of `src` : http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/184fseew/23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with IE11, where using % in `img.src` throws an error: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/997939/ie11-imageelement-setattribute-fails-with-invalid-argument-when-key-is-src-and-value-has-a-percent

There are two solutions here, depending on whether or not you need the `src` attribute to be set. The first one is to use `data-src` instead of `src`:

```
$timeout(function() {
     _this.setAttribute('data-src', holderSrc)
     Holder.run({
         images: _this,
         nocss: true
     });
 });
```

This is the cleaner solution and one I recommend.

The other solution would be to replace the element with a clone that has the proper `src` attribute value. This approach is not as clean and introduces overhead if you need to maintain references to the original image element. I only recommend this if the `src` attribute needs to be properly set.

Comment: Thx. It helped. I had to deal with the `data-ng-src` too, to keep the two-way binding. Here is the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/184fseew/23/. Only the first case does not work in IE11, but it is not the way I will operate.

Comment: Great to hear it helped.